# Spotify doesn't start

Tags: gtk, crash, spotify

Spotify doesn't start and I don't know where to search for the problem.

When I start `spotify` from the terminal, I get this:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

Comment: Firzt,i should understand what is module.

Comment: What's your Ubuntu release? Could you please [edit] your question to describe how you installed Spotify? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently these errors can be ignored. I had the same issue but was able to get it to work again by re-installing (in my case from snap):

```
snap remove spotify
snap install spotify
```

Afterwards I still see these messages when starting `spotify` from the command line (terminal). But the client starts nevertheless.